# How to Move two Horizontaly opposite edges on Rubik's Cube

Tags: rubiks-cube

I solved my 3x3 Rubik's cube, but then saw that two pieces were flipped and needed to be moved to the other pieces' spot. I have looked for solutions ,but they all are only about different spots. I don't know what to do without ruining the rest.

By flipped I mean the two pieces need to move to the other edges spot. My cube is all solved just that two pieces need to switch to each others spot.

Comment: Is your rubik’s cube A 3x3?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what "flipped" means, and which two pieces are flipped?

Comment: could you take a photo of the current circumstances of the rubiks cube and show it here? this can help us help you. thanks!

Comment: You could switch the stickers, noone would know (except us :D)